# "На предприятии" или "в предприятии"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Работать *в* или *на* предприятии?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Работать НА предприятии (на заводе, на порностудии, на складе).

С другой стороны: поучаствовать В рисковом предприятии (в авантюре, в действиях развратного характера, в заговоре).

Смотрите § 199 в ["Справочнике по правописанию и стилистике"](http://rosental-book.ru/styli_xlv.html#sect199) Розенталя:

*Иногда сказывается исторически сложившаяся традиция; ср.: в деревне – на хуторе, в селе – первый на селе работник; **в учреждении – на предприятии**, в переулке – на улице; ср. также: в комбинате бытового обслуживания – на мясокомбинате.*