# Какой предлог выбрать: в или на?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как правильно: "На фото изображена погрузка вскрышной породы В угольном разрезе" или "На фото изображена погрузка вскрышной породы НА угольном разрезе"

Comment: Подобный вопрос был отвечен: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/429586/%d0%9d%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8

Comment: «На фото изображена...» — не хорошо, вызывает вопрос: кем изображена. По крайней мере: «фото погрузки», или — «на снимке: процесс погрузки».

Answer (score 1):

В Нацкорпусе встречаются оба варианта. По-моему, говоря "на разрезе", подразумевают предприятие (работать на предприятии), в этом случае часто добавляют название разреза. Применительно к Вашему случаю, я думаю, все зависит от контекста. Если понятно, о каком разрезе идет речь, то "**на разрезе**", если о каком-то неопределенном разрезе, то "**в разрезе**"

Примеры из Нацкорпуса.

1.Игнат Бакин. Уральские ученые: часть Карпинска может затопить паводковыми водами // Новый регион 2, 2010.03.10
 По словам Афанасьева, уровень воды в угольном разрезе поднимается даже в сухую погоду. [Игнат Бакин. Уральские ученые: часть Карпинска может затопить паводковыми водами // Новый регион 2, 2010.03.10]

2.Латыпов Дмитрий. СВАДЬБА ХОЗЯИНА // Труд-7, 2005.11.07
 Но ситуация такова, что средняя зарплата в угольном разрезе на сегодня всего лишь 11―12 тысяч рублей, в то время как прожиточный минимум в крае составляет для работающего 4146 рублей, а для безработного―3845. [Латыпов Дмитрий. СВАДЬБА ХОЗЯИНА // Труд-7, 2005.11.07]

---

1.В. Катков. Баня в русской печи // «Наука и жизнь», 2008
 В 1975 году вернулся в родной город, где почти 25 лет проработал на угольном разрезе начальником участка, заместителем главного инженера, а затем и главным инженером разреза до самого закрытия предприятия. [В. Катков. Баня в русской печи // «Наука и жизнь», 2008]

2.Александр Волков. Пишу вам с глубокой обидой на наших депутатов… (2003) // «Восточно-Сибирская правда» (Иркутск), 2003.06.21 
 Из них 10 лет на железной дороге, в том числе и два военных года; один год в колхозе; 42 года ― на угольном разрезе «Черемховский». [Александр Волков. Пишу вам с глубокой обидой на наших депутатов… (2003) // «Восточно-Сибирская правда» (Иркутск), 2003.06.21]

3.Станислав Гагарин. «А девочку зовут дорога...» // «Техника - молодежи», 1977
 Занимался гражданским строительством и в Экибастузе, на угольном разрезе «Богатырь». [Станислав Гагарин. «А девочку зовут дорога...» // «Техника - молодежи», 1977]

4.Юрий Трифонов. Утоление жажды (1959-1962)
 Ермасов сшиб Фефлова одним ударом (спасти старика было невозможно, уж очень явно и глупо он проштрафился) и посадил на его место некоего Карабаша: говорили, что он вовсе даже и не ирригатор, а работал главным механиком вскрышного участка на угольном разрезе где-то на Урале. [Юрий Трифонов. Утоление жажды (1959-1962)]

Answer (score 0):

В Нацкорпусе **4 примера "на угольном разрезе", "в угольном разрезе" не встречается:**

... говорили, что он вовсе даже и не ирригатор, а работал главным механиком вскрышного участка **на угольном разрезе** где-то на Урале. [Юрий Трифонов. Утоление жажды (1959-1962)]

Из них 10 лет на железной дороге, в том числе и два военных года; один год в колхозе; 42 года ― **на угольном разрезе «Черемховский»**. [Александр Волков. 2003.06.21]

Здесь имеется в виду ***на предприятии,*** которое названо ***угольным разрезом*** (как завод, фабрика).